# Is there a restart via gate type option in FM8?

Tags: synthesizer

FM8 seems to change timbre at random on different midi hits.  Massive also does this, but you can change the restart via gate option so that the oscillators always start at the same phase each hit.

In FM synthesis, this free running oscilator type effect can be very pronounced, and can completely alter the timbre between two identical MIDI hits.

Is there some way round this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under each Operator tab (A-F), the option is called "Key Sync" in the Waveform section. This toggles between Key Sync (aka Restart via Gate in Massive) and Free Run.

This is different than the Key Sync option found on the Ops tab. That Key Sync is also enabled per-operator, but it controls whether the arpeggiator restarts on key press or picks up where it left off.